# Linux - Docker MySQL Image - CREATE MYSQL_USER

Tags: mysql, linux, image, bash, docker

I am new to docker containers, and I am working on automating some MySQL tasks. By using bash scripts I am able to automate the creation and dump of Databases but now i am trying to create the new user getting input from the command line and it is not working. this is my script:

```
sudo docker run -it --link testing1:mysql --rm mysql/mysql-server:5.7.11 sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -e"CREATE USER 'docker'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tester'"'
```

the error message i receive is :

```
+ EXPECTED_ARGS=2
+ E_BADARGS=65
++ which mysql
+ MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql

+ sudo docker run -it --link testing1:mysql --rm mysql/mysql-server:5.7.11 sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"

-e"CREATE USER docker@% IDENTIFIED BY tester"'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '% IDENTIFIED BY tester' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The solution was to set the ENV variables to get the user input like like this:

SOURCE="'%'"
USER="'$1'"
PASSWORD="'$2'"


 and then this:     docker exec -it ctb /usr/bin/mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -pmario123 -e "GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ${USER}@${SOURCE} IDENTIFIED BY ${PASSWORD};"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the `%` (to allow connections from any ip) in quotations.

`CREATE USER docker@'%' IDENTIFIED BY tester`

Comment: oops, the password `tester` needs to be in quotations as well, other wise MySQL will think that you are specifying a plugin rather than a password string.

Comment: this is the actual script, the one you are looking at is the error message:

CREATE USER 'docker'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tester'

I thought that there was a problem with escaping the quotations but i tired pretty much everything and still didnt make any progress; i am starting to think that this is an issue of the docker mysql image

Answer (score 0):

You can use this image as a template. 
https://github.com/kliewkliew/mysql-adventureworks

I used 
`mysql -e'GRANT ALL ON *.* TO user@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "password";'`

Comment: oh thanks for the tip, how do you start a new instance with this image?

Comment: i tried docker run -it --name myname kliew/mysql-adventureworks
 but it freezes on starting mysqld.

Comment: also i should be more specific, what i want is to be able to create a new user at anytime, not just on creation, is there a way to do that?

Comment: That is expected. You need to create a new terminal session if you want to use bash. `docker exec -it myname bash`. At any point, you can execute `mysql -e'GRANT ALL ON *.* TO user@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "password";'` inside thi new terminal to create a new user.

Comment: could you please give me an example of how would you create a script that does all that?